# Tikz automaton placed too far to the right

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, diagrams, automata

So I'm having a bit of trouble drawing an automaton that I've created. I've been looking around for a while to no real avail, so I decided to just ask the question myself: when I make an automaton (I'll post mine), the entire diagram is too far to the right. Given the default spacing that I had was 3.5cm, the diagram is perfectly visible throughout, nothing is cut off, but when I wish to space the nodes out a little more, say, to 5.5cm, then half of my automaton falls off the right side of the screen (ie it appears to never get drawn).

I've tried altering to starting position of the first node, under the assumption that "every other node is just constructed around the first one", but that didn't work. I tried using `at (x, y)`, I've tried using `\centering`, I've tried loads of things (half of which came from this very site), but sadly, I cannot figure it out. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%as of the 20th f August, 2013, all of the self-loops
%for all of the nodes are incomplete (ie if any
%nodes have self loops, the labels are not quite finished)



\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5.5cm,
                semithick]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

\node[initial,state] (1)                    {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (2) [below of=1]       {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (3) [above left of=1]  {$s_3$};
\node[state]         (4) [above right of=1] {$s_4$};
\node[state]         (5) [below left of=3]  {$s_5$};
\node[state]         (6) [below right of=4] {$s_6$};
\node[state]         (7) [below of=2]       {$s_7$};
\node[state]         (8) [below of=5]       {$s_8$};
\node[state]         (9) [below of=6]       {$s_9$};

\path 
(1) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below, pos=.3] {PG$\_$ON} (2)
    edge [bend left]    node [sloped, above] {CSP}  (3)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] [swap, pos = .2] {CPSU}    (4)
    edge [loop above, looseness=30] node {PSUFull}  (1)

(2) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, above] {CSP}  (5)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] {CPSU} (6)
    edge    node [swap, pos=.4, sloped, above] {PSUFull}    (7)
    edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below, pos=.7] {PG$\_$OFF} (1)
    edge [loop above]   node {lowSP} (2)

(3) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below] {lowSP} (1)
    edge [bend right]   node [left, sloped, above] {PG$\_$ON} (5)
    edge [loop above]   node {CSP} (3)

(4) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] {PG$\_$ON} (6)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (1)
    edge [loop above]   node {CPSU} (4)

(5) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below] {lowSP} (2)
    edge    node [sloped, above] {PSUFull} (8)
    edge [bend right]   node [above, sloped] {PG$\_$OFF} (3)
    edge [loop left, looseness=20]  node {CSP} (5)

(6) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below]  {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (2)
    edge    node [swap, sloped, above] {PSUFull} (9)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (4)
    edge [loop right, looseness=20]     node {CPSU} (6)

(7) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below]  {CSP} (8)
    edge [bend right]   node [swap, sloped, above] {CPSU} (9)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (1)
    edge [loop below]   node {lowSP} (7)

(8) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, swap] {lowSP} (7)
    edge [bend left = 80]   node [pos=.2, sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (3)
    edge [loop left]    node {CSP} (8)

(9) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (7)
    edge [bend right=80]    node [swap, pos=.2] {PG$\_$OFF} (4)
    edge [loop right]   node {CPSU} (9);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the image:

[image: My failure of an automata]

I'm really sorry if this isn't formatted properly or if this question has been asked before/is really foolish. I'm just stuck =/. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This isn't a fix so much as a cheap workaround: have you tried using the `standalone` document class?  (It even has a `tikz` option.)  That way, you can just `\includegraphics` the generated PDF; compilation is a lot faster that way, too.

Comment: Ad what you did for the image was OK; one of us will almost always notice and come edit it in for you :)

Comment: Thanks Sean! I actually did try using `standalone` as the document class, (`\documentclass{standalone}`) but it didn't quite work. I get an error saying `standalone.cls not found`. I think I had it working earlier such that it compiled, however it didn't actually appear to do anything. I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious here, as, if you can't tell, I'm very new to tikz and actually LaTeX itself (as in I downloaded Kile a week ago).

Comment: Strange... which distribution are you using? what is the output of `kpsewhich standalone.cls`?  I'll post the complete `standalone` example.

Comment: Just saw your answer, realized I'm a fool. Thanks so much! I wish I could up-vote it, but alas, I am but a noob.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options:

#### Increase paper size:

Probably not a viable option, but for completion:
Refer to the [LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#More_size_options_with_geometry) for an exhaustive list.

#### Decrease margins:

```
\usepackage[margin=1pt]{geometry}
```

In this case, there is simply not enough room.

#### Use the `standalone` class:

Externalize the image into a different file.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[...]
...
```

This puts it all on one page which can easily be included in your main document with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mytikzautomaton}`
This can also speed up compilation of the main document *considerably*.

[image]

#### Scale the entire drawing:

This requires quite a bit of fiddling to look good and isn't a very robust solution, but requires the least amount of effort.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[..., scale=0.9,
      every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
...
```

---

Complete example using `standalone`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, positioning}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=5.5cm,
                semithick,
                scale=0.9, every node/.style={scale=0.9}]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

\node[initial,state] (1)                    {$s_1$};
\node[state]         (2) [below of=1]       {$s_2$};
\node[state]         (3) [above left of=1]  {$s_3$};
\node[state]         (4) [above right of=1] {$s_4$};
\node[state]         (5) [below left of=3]  {$s_5$};
\node[state]         (6) [below right of=4] {$s_6$};
\node[state]         (7) [below of=2]       {$s_7$};
\node[state]         (8) [below of=5]       {$s_8$};
\node[state]         (9) [below of=6]       {$s_9$};

\path 
(1) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below, pos=.3] {PG$\_$ON} (2)
    edge [bend left]    node [sloped, above] {CSP}  (3)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] [swap, pos = .2] {CPSU}    (4)
    edge [loop above, looseness=30] node {PSUFull}  (1)

(2) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, above] {CSP}  (5)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] {CPSU} (6)
    edge    node [swap, pos=.4, sloped, above] {PSUFull}    (7)
    edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below, pos=.7] {PG$\_$OFF} (1)
    edge [loop above]   node {lowSP} (2)

(3) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below] {lowSP} (1)
    edge [bend right]   node [left, sloped, above] {PG$\_$ON} (5)
    edge [loop above]   node {CSP} (3)

(4) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, above] {PG$\_$ON} (6)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (1)
    edge [loop above]   node {CPSU} (4)

(5) edge [bend left]    node [sloped, below] {lowSP} (2)
    edge    node [sloped, above] {PSUFull} (8)
    edge [bend right]   node [above, sloped] {PG$\_$OFF} (3)
    edge [loop left, looseness=20]  node {CSP} (5)

(6) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below]  {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (2)
    edge    node [swap, sloped, above] {PSUFull} (9)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (4)
    edge [loop right, looseness=20]     node {CPSU} (6)

(7) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below]  {CSP} (8)
    edge [bend right]   node [swap, sloped, above] {CPSU} (9)
    edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (1)
    edge [loop below]   node {lowSP} (7)

(8) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, swap] {lowSP} (7)
    edge [bend left = 80]   node [pos=.2, sloped, below] {PG$\_$OFF} (3)
    edge [loop left]    node {CSP} (8)

(9) edge [bend right]   node [sloped, below] {PSU$\neg$Thresh} (7)
    edge [bend right=80]    node [swap, pos=.2] {PG$\_$OFF} (4)
    edge [loop right]   node {CPSU} (9);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no idea how you did this so quickly, but this is brilliant, thank you!

Comment: @Wascallian An entire semester of computation theory. `;)` You're most welcome.

Comment: And another minor note: these solutions work with most, if not all, TikZ drawings.

Comment: Great answer. However, when I use standalone, it makes a two-page pdf, only the second of which has a figure. \includegraphics{} then only shows the first blank page. How does one resolve this?

Comment: @sautedman sounds like you should increase the paper size on your standalone document. i would ask a new question, though – follow-up questions like this are oft forgotten.

Comment: @SeanAllred It looks like it was because I was using `\centering`. I posted a question as to why this should be (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252853/standalone-makes-two-page-document).